# Not getting the page using Node.js and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I could not get the required partial view using Node.js and Angular.js. My code is below.

server.js:

```
var port=8989;
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var app=express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.use(morgan('dev'));                  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))   
app.use(bodyParser.json())    
app.use(methodOverride());
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
})
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server is running on the port"+port);
```

The above is my server side file.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="FGDP">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Chinmaya Sahu">
    <title>...:::WELCOME TO FGDP:::...</title>
    <link href="css/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angularuirouter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/loginRoute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angularcaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-messages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angularuibootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div  ui-view>

</div>
<!--<base href="/Gofasto/">-->
<!--<base href="/spesh/">-->
</body>
</html>
```

First user will get the above page.Inside `ui-view` the partial view will render which is given below.

public/js/loginRoute.js:

```
$stateProvider
     .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
```

Here `login.html` is the partial view and its not coming.My directory structure is given below.

```
1)root directory

  -> Node_modules
  -> Public
       =>JS
       =>CSS
       =>Controller
 -> View
 -> server.js
 ->Package.json
```

Comment: You are binding `public` folder to static path `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); ` That's why files in `view` are not rendering on client.

Comment: One solution is to put `views` in `public` folder

Comment: @MukeshSharma : Ok.let me to try.

Comment: @MukeshSharma : Yes,thank you.its coming now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the following line that binds the content inside public folder to the root path.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

e.g. by accessing http://localhost:8989/js/loginRoute.js, you can get javascript file.

Your `view` folder doesn't reside under public directory. Hence, you are getting `404` for http://localhost:8989/view/login.html

One possible solution is to move `view` directory inside `public`.